# Bash: move and rename files to parent directory

Tags: bash, loops, unix, mv

I have the following working code:

```
for f in */*/*.jpg; do rename 's#/picture#p#' "$f"; done &&
for f in */*.jpg; do rename 's#/subfolder#s#' "$f"; done
```

However, this does not work with the following verison of rename: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

The following folder structure:

```
folder1/subfolder1/picture1.png
folder1/subfolder2/picture1.png
folder1/subfolder2/picture2.png
folder2/subfolder1/picture1.png
```

should be converted into the following structure

```
f1s1p1.png
f1s2p1.png
f1s2p2.png
f2s1p1.png
```

Comment: You need to use the `rename` known variously as `Perl rename` and `prename` in order to use regexes like you want to.

Comment: If you really use the `rename` you are refering to in the link (there are several utilites of this name around; mine is different), note that you invoke it with two arguments only, while according to the man page, you need to provide at least 3 arguments to perform a renaming. Aside from this, there is no substring looking like `s#/picture#p#` in any of your filenames, so even if you had provided a filename to rename, no renaming would take place.

Comment: BTW, did you **verify** that you have indeed that _rename_ which corresponds to the man-page you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the man page for [rename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) that you linked yourself: the command takes two strings "from" and "to" (plus a list of files).

> **Synopsis**
>
> **rename** from to file...

You could just try the following:

```
for f in */*.jpg */*/*.jpg; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1\2/g' | tr -d /)"; done
```

This will, however, leave the original folders in place which you will then have to remove manually.

Comment: is the condition of the loop meant to be?

`zsh: no matches found: */*.jpg`

Comment: I don't know zsh, but this error seems to say that there are no jpg files in any of your immediate subdirectories.